# Difference in Dependency Resolution based on JDK Version in Apache CXF

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF in my project and see a difference in the dependency tree when I'm compiling using different Java Versions. How is maven or CXF controlling this change in the dependency tree based on Java Version?

From whatever I could gather we can either use a Maven Profile with Activation on a specific Java Version or an enforcer plugin but both of these configurations are missing in CXF.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.5.5/cxf-core-3.5.5.pom

JDK 8 Dependency Tree

```
[INFO] org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:bundle:3.5.5
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:5.0.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.4:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.36:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:test
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.3.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.22:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:jar:1.10.3:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.api:jar:1.0.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.quiesce:org.apache.aries.quiesce.api:jar:1.0.0:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.api:jar:1.1.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:blueprint-parser:jar:1.6.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.7:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.18:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:6.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:jar:6.0.0:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.msv:msv-core:jar:2013.6.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.msv:xsdlib:jar:2013.6.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  |  \- relaxngDatatype:relaxngDatatype:jar:20020414:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb:isorelax:jar:20090621:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-io:jar:1.2.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:jar:1.2.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO]    \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:test
```

JDK 16 Dependency Tree

```
[INFO] org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:bundle:3.5.5
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:5.0.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.4:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.36:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:test
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.3.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.22:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.22:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:jar:1.10.3:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.api:jar:1.0.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.quiesce:org.apache.aries.quiesce.api:jar:1.0.0:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.api:jar:1.1.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:blueprint-parser:jar:1.6.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.7:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.18:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:6.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:jar:6.0.0:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- net.java.dev.msv:msv-core:jar:2013.6.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.msv:xsdlib:jar:2013.6.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  |  \- relaxngDatatype:relaxngDatatype:jar:20020414:provided (optional) 
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb:isorelax:jar:20090621:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-io:jar:1.2.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:jar:1.2.1:provided (optional) 
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO] +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.soap:jakarta.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:3.9:test
[INFO]    \- org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:jar:3.9:test
```

Jars that get added in JDK 16,

```
[INFO] +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.soap:jakarta.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:3.9:test
[INFO]    \- org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:jar:3.9:test
```

I'm trying to understand how a dependency say geronimo-jta_1.1_spec is getting resolved or added to the tree when compiling using JDK 16.

Comment: there is `java9-plus` profile defined in parent pom (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-parent/3.5.5/cxf-parent-3.5.5.pom), which adds extra dependencies.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it?